# Context.io in android application

Tags: android, email

Is it possible to use [context.io](https://context.io/) in android application ? I have searched for a long time. [In their website,](https://context.io/how-it-works/dev-tools) they mentioned to provide client libraries for PHP, Ruby, Python and Node.js only. And in the [Github account](https://github.com/ContextIO) they provide [context.io for ios](https://github.com/contextio/contextio-ios). Then why not for android ?? 
yes, there is one app says [Context.io for java](https://github.com/contextio/ContextIO.java) which is the exact copy of PHP. But the author mentions its not implemented completely and it wont work as exactly as PHP version.

Answer (score 2):

I was the same issue and for the solution, I have developed an Android Library based on Scribble to communicate with Contextio.

This is how it works:

```
String account_id = "your account id";
String consumerkey = "your contextio consumer key";
String consumersecret = "your contextio consumer secret";
link="https://api.context.io/2.0/accounts/" + account_id + "/messages";
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                    .provider(OAuthProvider.class)
                    .apiKey(consumerKey)
                    .apiSecret(consumerSecret)
                    .build();
OAuthRequest request = null;
request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, link);
Token accessToken = new Token("", "");
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
String b = response.getBody();
Log.d("OAuthTask",response.getBody());
```

You can check complete async library here:

https://github.com/rishijash/Contextio-Android

Comment: I have used the code and  instruction, you specified in github and i am getting this following exception " org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service. "

Answer (score 1):

Although they do not provide a library, but they have a [REST API](https://context.io/how-it-works/api-overview) which can be used with a REST client e.g. [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). This maybe not as convenient as using a dedicated library, but all of their services become accessible.